# $SL(2, Z_2)$ closed under multiplication

Tags: matrices, determinant

How can $SL(2, Z_2)$ (i.e matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and determinant 1) form a group, when:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{pmatrix}$ * $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&2 \end{pmatrix}$ which doesn't have entries in $\mathbb{Z_2}$

and if we let $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&2 \end{pmatrix} =$ $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ then $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $-1$

So either way we have the matrices are not closed under multiplication. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1=-1$ in $\mathbb Z_2$, and you should reduce all entries modulo $2$, so the first matrix has a zero in the bottom right entry.

i.e: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$